# Python looping through lists

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have a list called:

```
word_list_pet_image = [['beagle', '01125.jpg'], ['saint', 'bernard', '08010.jpg']]
```

There is more data in this list but I kept it short.  I am trying to iterate through this list and check to see if the word is only alphabetical characters if this is true append the word to a new list called

```
pet_labels = []
```

So far I have:

```
word_list_pet_image = []
for word in low_pet_image:
    word_list_pet_image.append(word.split("_"))

for word in word_list_pet_image:
    if word.isalpha():
        pet_labels.append(word)
        print(pet_labels)
```

For example I am trying to put the word `beagle` into the list pet_labels, but skip `01125.jpg`. see below.

```
pet_labels = ['beagles', 'Saint Bernard']
```

I am getting a atributeError

> AtributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isalpha'

I am sure it has to do with me not iterating through the list properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to join alphabetical words in each sublist. A list comprehension would be effective here.

```
word_list = [['beagle', '01125.jpg'], ['saint', 'bernard', '08010.jpg']]

pet_labels = [' '.join(w for w in l if w.isalpha()) for l in word_list]

>>> ['beagle', 'saint bernard']
```

Comment: I was not aware of list comprehension going to read up on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have lists of lists, so the brute force method would be to nest loops. like:

```
for pair in word_list_pet_image:
    for word in pair:
        if word.isalpha():
            #append to list
```

Another option might be single for loop, but then slicing it:

```
for word in word_list_pet_image:
    if word[0].isalpha():
        #append to list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
word_list = [['beagle', '01125.jpg'], ['saint', 'bernard', '08010.jpg']]
```

---

Why not `list comprehension` (only if non-all alphabetical letters element is always at last):

```
pet_labels = [' '.join(l[:-1]) for l in word_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word_list_pet_image.append(word.split("_"))
```

`.split()` returns lists, so `word_list_pet_image` itself contains lists, not plain words.